# Sending emails to list: Loop through each or Bcc?

Tags: email

Does it make more sense to loop through each email or to send one email and add the list to the Bcc? I've heard different answers and I'm not sure why one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention is to send one message per recipient domain, and within that domain, to effectively Bcc: all users within that domain.

Unless you have very specific needs, just Bcc: everyone and use your ISP's smarthost to handle the real work, though.

Comment: This seems to conflict with Martin Smith's answer

Comment: Nor really. If you want a unique `To:` header on each message, then obviously you cannot use `Bcc:`. If you send to just a few hundred recipients, how exactly you send them is not very significant.

Answer (score 0):

Send individual emails if you want the email's "To" field to contain the receivers email address otherwise Bcc should be fine if you are not sending to hundreds of recipients.

This [site](http://www.brilliantthinking.net/2006/04/29/is-it-ok-to-use-bcc-for-a-mailing-list/) has more information.